# What is the rationale behind this code block in java?

Tags: java, initialization, construct

What is the rationale behind making this kind of code valid in java? Does it exist for some particular reason or is it just a byproduct of other Java language design decisions? Can't you just use the consructor to achieve the same effect?

```
class Student
{
    {
        System.out.println("Called when Student class is instantiated.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

One point is that it will execute *whichever* constructor is called. If you have several constructors and they don't call each other (for whatever reason, e.g. each wanting to call a directly-corresponding superclass constructor) this is one way of making sure the same code is executed for all constructors, without putting it in a method which could be called elsewhere.

It's also potentially useful when you're writing an anonymous class - you can't write a constructor, but you *can* write an initializer block. I've seen this used for JMock tests, for example.

Comment: +1 for the anonymous class mention. Definitely my most frequent use for initializer blocks.

Comment: I knew it wouldn't be long before Jon's answer would climb to the top. Upvoted for the mention of usage in an anonymous class.

Comment: Another good thing about initializer blocks: they can assign final instance fields. This is not possible with a function called from multiple constructors.

Comment: Did we need another reason not to use final?

Comment: @Stephan: Are you suggesting that immutability is a bad thing? I'm fond of making methods, classes and static/instance variables wherever possible...

Comment: I do consider that kind of immutability to be a bad thing, yes. I like having immutable instances, but have encountered too many finals that needed overriding. Design for reusability is difficult, there is no need to make it more difficult.

Comment: @Stephan: I think we'll have to agree to differ. I find it's much easier to design for composition via immutable types and simple interfaces than to try to design inheritance trees of mutable types and then somehow use them reliably.

Comment: The situation might have improved, but in early java (till 1.4 or so) I've never seen it used sensibly. But I tend to push things to the limits, and often need better implementations than are provided. String is the obvious example of too early binding.

Comment: @Stephan: So you'd make String mutable? Eek. As I say, I think we'll have to agree to differ.

Comment: The more severe early binding problem is that it should have been an interface instead of a class.

Comment: @Stephan: *Possibly*. (There's CharSequence now, but that's very limited.) I wonder what the performance implications would have been like though...

Comment: this means you can do "new ArrayList<String>(){{add("one");}};"

Answer (score 20):

It's called an [initializer block](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

> The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor. Therefore, this approach can be used to share a block of code between multiple constructors.

Comment: That's awesome. I knew about blocks but didn't know they could used for constructors. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 5):

It called *init block*. In such block you can perform logic that are same for *all* constructions also you can separate *declaration* and *initialization* of same fields.

**upd** and of course *double brace* initialization, like

```
List<Integer> answers = new ArrayList<Integer>(){{add(42);}}
```

Comment: "Double brace initialization" is the same thing as what @Jon mentioned: using an initializer block in an anonymous class.

Answer (score 5):

This is an initialization block. As mentioned by Matt Ball, they are copied into each constructor.

You might be interested to know about **static initialization blocks** (also in Matt's [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)):

```
public class Foo {
    static {
        System.out.println("class Foo just got initialized!");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("an instance of Foo just got initialized!");
    }
}
```